# Using C++11 regex to capture the contents of a context-free-grammar file

Tags: c++, regex, parsing, context-free-grammar, lexer

## Preface

I'm trying to write my own context-free-grammar specification, to associate with the rules of my lexer/parser. It is meant to be similar to that of [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)'s, where upper-case identifiers classify as a Lexer rule and lower-case identifiers classify as a Parser rule. It is meant to accept any combination of string literals and/or regular expressions for lexer rules, and any combination of lexer/regex rules and/or other parser identifiers for parser rules. Each rule in is the format of ***<identifier>:<expression>;***

Here's an example of the grammar:

```
integer      : DIGIT+;        //parser rule containing at least one lexer rule
twodigits    : DIGIT DIGIT;   //parser rule containing two consecutive lexer rules
DIGIT        : [0-9];         //lexer rule containing regex
string       : '"' CHAR* '"'; //parser rule containing zero or more 
                              //  lexer rules, wrapped in two string literals
CHAR         : (LCHAR|UCHAR); //lexer rule containing two lexer rules which
                              //  will later evaluate to one of two tokens
LCHAR        : [a-z];         //lexer rule containing regex
UCHAR        : [A-Z];         //lexer rule containing regex
SPACE        : ' ';           //lexer rule containing string literal
```

---

## Problem

The trouble I'm having is the ability to match the expression strings, since their contents tend to vary.
I have originally written:
`([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)(?:\s*)(?:\:)(?:\s*)((?:\'?).*(?:\'?)(?:\;))`
as the match rule, which does okay for a single string literal expression surrounded by single quotes, but I need to expand this to allow for multiple non-greedy string literals, and combined statements separated by any number of whitespace. I am not concerned with matching potential regex's within a matched expression, or even capturing segregated parts of the expression, as this is handled later on by a separate regex operation, so really I just need to *validate* identifiers and expressions...

***All in all***, I need the regex_search operation to look through the grammar's contents, using the following syntax for matches:

- **A valid identifier**, starting with one or more lower or uppercase letters, optionally followed by any number of alphanumeric characters (which optionally can contain any number of underscore characters inbetween, as long as the identifier does not start or end with one).
- **Any number of** whitespace characters, tabs, newlines etc, without capturing it.
- **A colon** without capturing it.
- **Any number of** whitespace characters, tabs, newlines etc, without capturing it.
- **At least one of**: (in any order) any number of string literals (enclosed in single quotes, without capturing the quotes), any number of lexer/parser identifiers, any number of regex's (enclosed in square brackets). The result of this match rule should capture the entire expression as a single string, which will later go through a post-processing stage.
- **Any number of** whitespace characters, tabs, newlines etc, without capturing it.
- **A semicolon** optionally followed by any uncaptured whitespace.
- **Optionally, any** number of uncaptured spaces followed by a single captured line comment
- **Any number of** whitespace characters, tabs, newlines etc, without capturing it.

---

## Question

Is it possible to place this into a single regex_search operation?
I've messed around in [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) and just can't seem to get it right...

---

## Update

So far, I've been able to come up with the following:

```
#/////////////////////
# Identifier
#/////////////////////
(
    (?:[a-zA-Z]+)           # At least one lower/uppercase letter
    (?:
        (?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)   # Zero or more alphanumeric/underscore characters,
        (?:\w+)             # explicitly followed by one or more alphanumeric
    )?                      #   characters
)

#/////////////////////
# Separator
#/////////////////////
(?:\s*)                     # Any amount of uncaptured whitespace
(?:\:)                      # An uncaptured colon
(?:\s*)                     # Any amount of uncaptured whitespace

#///////////////////////
# Expression
#///////////////////////
(
    # String Literals:
    (?:\'?)                 # An optional single quote,
    (?:                     #   which is meant to start and end a string
        (?:[^'\\] | \\.)*   #   literal, but issues several problems for
    )                       #   me (see comments below, after this code block)
    (?:\'?)
    # Other expressions
    # ????????????
)

#/////////////////////
# Line End
#/////////////////////
(?:\s*)                     # Any amount of uncaptured whitespace
(?:\;)                      # An uncaptured colon
(?:\s*)                     # Any amount of uncaptured whitespace
```

As you can see, I have *identifiers*, *separators* and *line-ends* working perfectly. But expressions are where I'm totally stuck!
**How can I tell the regex library that I want *EITHER* a non-greedy string literal, *OR* any set of characters before the Line End, *AND* any number of them in any order?**
Even if I only allowed a single string literal, how would I say *"The closing single quote is NOT optional if the first one exists"*?

Comment: I haven't read your full question, but if you are parsing a free-grammar with C++11 regex, then it is not possible. A stack is necessary to parse context-free grammar (.NET or Perl flavor can do this, since they have construct that emulate a stack).

Comment: @nhahtdh How is it _not_ possible to parse a context-free (or any) grammar file? For each line, I'm really only trying to grab the non-terminal _(identifier)_ and terminal _(expression)_ strings. In theory, this is easy until you try to match any combination of string literals and other terminals as a single terminal expression.

Comment: Are you lexing or parsing? Lexing is always possible, but parsing CFG  with C++11 regex is not possible. (My comment earlier wrote "free-grammar", but should be read as "context-free grammar"). If your grammar is actually a regular grammar, instead of a "real" context-free grammar, then it is possible to parse with C++11 regex.

Comment: Both, actually. The plan is to parse the grammar to build a list of _identifiers_ and _expressions_, then post-process those expressions, building string literals into tokens and replacing terminal symbols in expressions with their equivalent non-terminal and/or regex values... and this is all before parsing the target input source, in a library I've pridefully named _"Parlex"_

Comment: Is the grammar for *expression* context-free or regular? Can you write the grammar for *expression* like how you describe *string* (with some sort of BNF syntax, instead of describing with words)?

Comment: But for now, this question is merely about handling the occurrence of (potentially) escaped string literals mixed, in with any other non-string-literal characters

Comment: Please edit it to focus on the part that you are stuck. There are too many things in your post that it is distracting.

Comment: I have been constantly editing this question - sectioning it into info about my CFG specification, my issue, my main question, and even an important update to my progress/question. If that's too much for you, ___just read the Update section___.

Comment: The reason I have done it this way is because, since we are talking about my own flavor of language, most people would prefer to know exactly what the rules of what they can and can't do while using regex to match the specification. It's harder to answer a question without enough information to do so...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25992/discussion-between-nhahtdh-and-rectangleequals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be flawless, and may require additional coding in how match results are handled, but this appears to work:

```
#/////////////////////
# Identifier
#/////////////////////
(
    (?:[a-zA-Z]+)
    (?:
        (?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)
        (?:\w+)
    )?
)

#/////////////////////
# Separator
#/////////////////////
(?:\s*\:\s*)

#///////////////////////
# Expression
#///////////////////////
(
    '(?:\\\\.|[^'])*'|[^']+     # Might need to be processed separately
)

#/////////////////////
# Line End
#/////////////////////
(?:\s*\;\s*)
```