# Extracting ONLY specific parts of a regex 'expression'

Tags: c++, regex, pattern-matching, string-literals

I have a list of expressions that I would like to validate, and extract specific parts of.
These expressions are allowed to have any combination of:

- String literals (possibly escaped, but not necessarily), denoted by single quotes
- Any number of characters *which are NOT* string literals and
  *are NOT* a line-end character, denoted by a semicolon

Valid expressions would start after a colon, and end with a semi-colon.
An example of a valid expression would be:

```
: This is an *expression* 'with' and 'without \'escaped\' string literals', 
which ends with a semicolon!;
```

And out of that expression, I would like to extract:

- `This is an *expression*`
- `'with'`
- `and`
- `'without \'escaped\' string literals'`
- `, which ends with a semicolon!`

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide more valid examples along with your expected output behavior?  Or a better description of what defines the borders of each chunk you want to extract?

Comment: Hello. Please look at the **Update** section of [THIS question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351153/using-c11-regex-to-capture-the-contents-of-a-context-free-grammar-file) if you want more info. I made this question because it has gradually changed over time, and no longer fit the previous contents of the question in that link.

Comment: I basically want to extract anything and everything between the colon and semicolon (except for leading and trailing whitespace), but separate string literals from everything else, and have it all grouped together based upon whether it is a string literal or not.

Comment: What language are you using?  There is probably existing code to do what you want.  In Perl, it's the Text::ParseWords or Text::Balanced module.

Comment: @AndyLester std::regex in C++, using the _regex_search()_ function

Comment: What you want looks like getting the results of multiple capture groups. This is possible in .net http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures.aspx and Perl 6 but not many others.

Comment: Regex is really more for matching tokens. I think you want to invest in a parser for such logic. It may be possible using a regex, but the expression will probably be more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @KennethK. Actually, this is [_for_ a lexer/parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351153/using-c11-regex-to-capture-the-contents-of-a-context-free-grammar-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spoke to RectangleEquals, the answer is std::regex re_("'(?:\\.|[^'])*'|[^']+");

Comment: actually, it's `std::regex re_("'(?:\\\\.|[^'])*'|[^']+");` since we have it inside a string literal itself.

Comment: For completeness: To be flex/DFA compatible it really should be  `std::regex re_("'(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\'])*'|[^']+");`, although this doesn't matter in the default ECMA mode as shown here.