# Replacing the contents of an expression in C++ [std::regex]

Tags: c++, regex, string, replace, semantics

Let's assume we have the string `ONE|(TWO|(THREE|FOUR))`...
Knowing that std::regex **does not** support recursion, how can we break this string down into an std::vector of strings, which (in order) contains:

- `THREE|FOUR`
- `TWO|{0}`
- `ONE|{1}`

The purpose of transforming this in the preceding manner is to create a traversable expression list, which should semantically represent a nested if/then statement. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Use parsing software like bison?

Comment: @Barmar Actually, I'm creating my own lexer/parser of sorts, using my own grammar specification which more closely resembles that of [ANTLR's](http://www.antlr.org). The purpose of accomplishing the above is to generate parsing code.

Comment: Then read any good textbook on writing parsers, they should explain how to implement this.

Comment: what's the formal grammar? Can you have something like `ONE|TWO|THREE`? What about `(ONE|TWO)|THREE`?

Comment: @Barmar I am following [The Dragon Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools#Second_edition) but It doesn't seem to go into any specific detail about this, and instead suggests to use premade parser generator tools like bison, which doesn't help me since I am in fact building my own generator.

Comment: @didierc yes, you can have both. A more detailed example of the grammar can be [found HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351153/using-c11-regex-to-capture-the-contents-of-a-context-free-grammar-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the inner most content first you can make use of lazy/ungreedy RegEx behaviour and match everything till a `)` with `(.*?)\)` or everything but round brackets with `\([^\)\(]+`.

Pseudocode:

```
while ( regex_match(string, regex) ) {
    add matches to vector
    replace matches in string with vector index in curly brackets
}
```

Example RegEx: `((?:\(|^)[^\)\(]+(?:\)|$))`
RegEx demo here: http://regex101.com/r/pJ4pO7

Comment: I tried to implement this [(see here)](http://pastebin.com/QqPmiuxy) but I just can't seem to get the implementation right [(see output here)](http://pastebin.com/dTARZ93g), and it just goes into an infinite loop... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i don't know C much but you have to use something like search_all if there are multiple matches on the same level as in my example and use a regex like this: `^<\\d+>$` to stop the loop

Comment: I actually just realized that the output is indeed correct, and all I needed was the exit strategy you've provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using a regex library to do lexing is a horrible way to go for anything non-trivial. When you get a match, you are not going to know *what* has matched without some post-processing. If you don't want to use third party libraries, then you need to seriously ask yourself if you want to write your own lexer generator for starters. I'm happy to give you tips if you want to do that.

Once you have reliable lexing working, you will find the next part a lot easier. You could then either write an ad-hoc parser or go on to write your own parser generator.